# Google Classroom Invalid Argument Errors

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-classroom

I'm running the "add a teacher" example code from here: https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users, using python 2.7. It was working earlier today, but now I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 93, in <module>
      main()
  File "test.py", line 79, in main
    body=teacher).execute()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client-1.4.12-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-x86_64/egg/googleapiclient/http.py", line 729, in execute
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/185092455/teachers?alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.">
```

I'm running it as the domain super admin, and requesting the scopes classroom.courses, classroom.rosters, and classroom.profile.emails. I get the same error when I use the "try it" box at the bottom of the API reference entry for courses.teachers/create.

What's going wrong? I suspect it has something to do with the permissions/OAuth key, but I don't really know.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? It seems to work for me: via the OAuth Playground I tried creating a course as an admin, and then adding another teacher to the course via a POST to courses.teachers, and the teacher was added successfully. Admin held the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters`.

Comment: Please verify that the course ID is still valid, and that the teacher email you are trying to add isn't already added to that course.